# What is a Hilbert space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I've just seen a question about Hilbert Subspaces.

This made me wonder what a Hilbert space is.

Can anyone explain in layman's terms?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Comment: Don’t worry, [even Hilbert himself was wondering](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53288#53288).

Comment: I looked at the Wikipedia article but was left bemused by "A vibrating string can be modeled as a point in a Hilbert space. The decomposition of a vibrating string into its vibrations in distinct overtones is given by the projection of the point onto the coordinate axes in the space."

Comment: The article is referring to a Fourier series expansion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series . Basically, you can write any periodic function (such as one vibration of a string) as a sum of sines and cosines. This makes it easier to work with. The set of all such expansions forms a "Hilbert space": you can add them, multiply them by constants, etc.

Comment: Do you know what a vector space is, by the way?

Comment: No I don't to be honest.  I think a vector is a two dimensional list of numbers.

Comment: Probably not a topic for a layman (i.e., someone who has no knowledge of "vector spaces").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For you are a programmer, here is an example involving $1$'s and $0$'s.

[Schrödinger's cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat) is argubably the most widespread "hard" science thought experiment that invaded the pop culture most.

The state of the cat lives in a Hilbert space. The following comic is pretty illustrative (from abstrusegoose):

[image: cat]

In this comic, several characteristics of Hilbert spaces are shown (not all though, for some mathematical facts are hard to interpret without rigorous formality).

1. **Vector in a vector space does not have to be two dimensional list of numbers**: "Vector" can be a very abstract function $\psi(x)$. Here it is the state of the cat, namely $|0\rangle$ (dead) and $|1\rangle$ (alive), later the author added a new discovered basis in this space $|\mathrm{LOL}\rangle$.
2. **Linearity**: The member of a Hilbert spaces can be linearly combined with another member in this Hilbert spaces:
   $$
   |\psi\rangle  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle +  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle,
   $$
   or rather for $\alpha^2+\beta^2 = 1$:
   $$
   |\psi\rangle  = \alpha|0\rangle +  \beta|1\rangle.
   $$
   We can get members in the same Hilbert space in a more abstract way.
3. **Inner product structure**: where this "inner product" can be view more abstractly as well other than $a\cdot b$. In this case, it can be interpreted as observation collapsing the states:  $0$ state inner product with an arbitrary state $\psi$
   $$
   \langle 0 | \psi \rangle = \alpha \langle 0 |0\rangle = \alpha .
   $$
   Once we observe the cat' status, the probability we observe the cat in $|0\rangle $ is $\alpha^2$. Inner product gives us the square root of the probability that we observe an arbitrary state $\psi$ in a fixed known state $0$.

Answer (score 6):

A Hilbert space is a complete inner product space.

Comment: ... and it is an abstract *vector* space of course.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the best explanation (and motivation for the subject) I know about that would be suitable for someone at the high school algebra to elementary calculus level are two chapters in the following book.

[**The Mathematical sciences: A Collection of Essays**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262030268) (1969). For the table of contents, see [here](https://catalog.uttyler.edu/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=93093) or [here](http://digitalcollections.library.cmu.edu/awweb/awarchive?type=file&item=53195).

See the chapters *Functional Analysis* by Jacob T. Schwartz (pp. 72-83) and *Vector Spaces and Their Applications* by Edward James McShane (pp. 84-96).

Also good is *Chapter 19: Functional Analysis* by Israel M. Gelfand in [**Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486409163). For the table of contents, see [here](http://web.doverpublications.com/cgi-bin/toc.pl/0486409163).